# Exporting SVG images from a webpage

Tags: image, svg, resources

I am trying to export the logo of one of our partners into SVG. Their website is [here](https://te-st.ru/).

The logo is the element that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried every single solution I have found on both **SO** and **Graphic Design SE** (installing Chrome plugins like *SVG Crowbar*, copying and pasting the HTML of the code into a file... etc) and nothing has worked so far. Whenever I've been able to paste the code of the SVG into a file and renamed it ".svg", the file couldn't open with Illustrator.

I have also not found a tool to validate / troubleshoot SVG codes (the way one can validate HTML with the W3C validator).

### **How can this vector image can be extracted as a vector image file from the website's code?** -

Comment: In browser console: console.log(document.querySelector('#icon-logo')); Then need to change symbol for svg.

Comment: I am not sure how to do what you are suggesting. In Chrome there is a "Console" tab I can open after Inspecting the element, but that's as far as I can go.

Comment: Yes on Mac: Command+Option+J. Windows: Control+Shift+J. A part of your issue is that the element you require is hidden behind something, so you can get it through the console.

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do after the panel opens after I do CMD+OPT+J?

Comment: paste in console.log(document.querySelector('#icon-logo')); press enter. copy paste code to editor, change symbol to svg. Save as yourfile.svg

Comment: There is no way to select the whole text in the console, only parts of the code at a time like "symbol" or "id="icon-logo"

Comment: The logo id using a symbol you have in an other svg element `#icon-logo` You need to use the code of the symbol inside the svg element you need

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the logo, and choose "Inspect".
2. The browser dev tools window should open with the `<svg>` tag highlighted.
3. Press F2. This opens that tag in the inline tag editor.
4. You'll see that the SVG is just a simple link to an SVG symbol elsewhere in the HTML

   ```
   <svg class="svg-icon icon-logo"><use xlink:href="#icon-logo"></use></svg>
   ```
5. You need to find that symbol. If you look further up in the HTML, you'll see another `<svg>` element. Click on the little arrow next to that.
6. You'll see a whole lot of `<symbol>` tags. Find the one with `id="icon-logo"`.
7. Select that one and press F2 again
8. Select the whole `<symbol>` including contents by using Ctrl-A (Cmd-A on Mac)
9. Copy and paste the whole symbol to a text editor
10. Change the `<symbol` to `<svg`, and the `</symbol>` at the end to `</svg>`
11. To make it work as a standalone SVG, you'll also need to add the right `xmlns` attribute:

    ```
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    ```
12. Save the file. Eg. as logo.svg

The file should now look like this *(I've trimmed out some of the path)*:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 191 33"><path d="M8.988 16.702a1.65 1.65 0 0 1-1.154-1.975l-1.15-.664..."></path></svg>
```